# Is there a way to handle multiple celery workers with the same task with atomic blocks?

Tags: django, multithreading, celery, atomic

I have this task

```
def some_task(self, param):
    do_some_stuff_that_might_break_with_models()
```

normally I could do this:

```
def some_task(self, param):
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            do_some_stuff_that_might_break_with_models()
    except:
        self.retry(....)
```

But by doing so, it seems like if I have a couple workers performing this task it'll lock the db because of the atomic block. But if I get rid of it my try except will get angry. How could I handle this? I've tried preprocessing my input with unique hashes and then dispatching each chunk to its own worker and getting rid of the atomic and try blocks but by doing so I lost the ability to retry/track what tasks failed. I can still see what failed from the admin panel through djcelery, but not within the task itself.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that you can lock the DB like this? I'd expect the context manager to exit on any exception, rolling back the transaction: [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**exit**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__exit__).

If you're using Redis and want to avoid concurrent access entirely, I've had success with [python-redis-lock](https://github.com/ionelmc/python-redis-lock) as a distributed lock. You can use it in a blocking mode or not.